# RegEx not capturing

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to extract out some information using RegEx but I cannot understand why one certain element is not capturing in the correct group.

Here's the expression

```
^[\\* ](?'sname'[A-Z]+)/(?'fname'[A-Z]+) (\\*(?'chdinf'(INF|CHD)))? (?'random'.+?) (?'cpn'CPN[\\* ][1234])(?'status'.+?) (?'tktno'[0-9]+)$
```

And here's a sample input

```
*SNAME/FNAME         *INF   CPN 2   XX XXXX      99999999999999
```

The `*INF` text should be captured in the `chdinf` group but it's not but instead is being captured by the `random` group.

The `*INF` text is optional information hence the `lazy ?` at the end of the grouping construct.

If I change the `random` construct to `(?'random' +?)` (space, rather than '.') then the Regex fails entirely.

PS: I've been using http://regexstorm.net/tester as a testing platform.

Comment: You regular expression seems quite contrived. Could you please clarify wich parts of the string are optional and in which forms each part can occur?

Comment: @Abbondanza - The question has now been answered to my satisfaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

I rebuild the regular expression from how I understood your requirements:

```
^[* ](?'sname'[A-Z]+)/(?'fname'[A-Z]+)\s+(\*(?'chdinf'INF|CHD))?\s+(?'random'\S+)?\s+(?'cpn'CPN[* ][1-4])\s+(?'status'.+?)\s+(?'tktno'[0-9]+)$
```

Most notably you were missing a variable amount of whitespaces inbetween the individual parts. I used `\s+` instead of  for that.

### Breakdown

```
Regex                        Matches...

^                            the beginning of the input string
  [* ]                       a space or a "*"
    (?'sname'[A-Z]+)         an upper case identifier
    /                        a "/" separator
    (?'fname'[A-Z]+)         another upper case identifier
  \s+                        at least one whitespace character
  (\*(?'chdinf'INF|CHD))?    a "*" followed by "INF" or "CHD" (optionally)
  \s+                        
  (?'random'\S+)?            at least one of all non-whitespace characters (optionally)
  \s+                        
  (?'cpn'CPN[* ][1-4])       "CPN" followed by a space or a "*" followed by a number 
                             between 1 and 4
  \s+                        
  (?'status'.+?)             anything (lazily)
  \s+                        
  (?'tktno'[0-9]+)           an interger number greater or equal 0
$                            the end of the input string.
```

## Test

For the following inputs...

```
*SNAME/FNAME  *INF   CPN 2   XX XXXX      99999999999999
 SNAME/FNAME  *INF   CPN 2   XX XXXX      99999999999999
*SNAME/FNAME  *INF   CPN*2   XX XXXX      99999999999999
*SNAME/FNAME         CPN 2   XX XXXX      99999999999999
*SNAME/FNAME  RAND   CPN 2   XX XXXX      99999999999999
```

...I got those matches with the [RegEx Storm Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

[image: String parts captured by the above regular expression]

(I removed the leading `^` as well as the trailing `$` from the regular expression and activated the *Multiline* option in order to test all input strings at once.)

Comment: Thanks! I improved it a little. Similarly to the optional _chdinf_ group, the _random_ group is now captured with `(?'random'\S+)?` instead of `(?'random'.+?)`. This makes sure it is always empty if there is no _random_ part. Previously it captured the whitespaces between the neighboring parts in case there was no _random_ part in the input string.

Answer (score 3):

You did not take the preceding white space into account. Try this:

```
^[\* ](?'sname'[A-Z]+)\/(?'fname'[A-Z]+) +(\*(?'chdinf'(INF|CHD)))? (?'random'.+?) (?'cpn'CPN[\* ][1234])(?'status'.+?) (?'tktno'[0-9]+)$
```

See the '+' I added before. Is this what you need?